# Почему добавляется только 1 последнее значение (each() jquery)?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.comments').each(function() {
    $('#comments_values').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: попробуйте везде заменить #comments_values на .comments_values

Comment: Как написано - так и работает. Возможно, нужно что-то типа 
<code>
$('#comments_values').val($('#comments_values').val() + $(this).text());
</code> ?

Comment: @ffeynmann, не помогло.

@Равнодушный, совсем не это. Мне нужно наоборот в поле #comments_values вставлять все значения .comments. Мой код почему-то добавляет 1 последнее значение. На самом деле их 3

Comment: val() - устанавливает значение, т.е. полностью заменяет то, что есть в значении элемента, на поступившее значение. Т.е. при выполнении Вашего кода значение #comments_values сначала становится .comments[0], потом .comments[1], ..., и в итоге .comments[k], где k - (число .comments - 1). Что именно не ясно?

Comment: @Равнодушный, так как сделать, чтобы все значения то добавляло? Выносил за пределы, но не помогло. Если не затруднит, напишите код :)

Comment: Вообще-то я его написал в первом же комментарии. Или все хотят скопипастить, а не подумать? )

Comment: ну я не копи-пастил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сначала дайте понять народу что у вас происходит в `html`, для меня сейчас это вот так выглядет:

```
<div class='comments'>1</div><br />
<div class='comments'>2</div><br />
<div class='comments'>3</div><br />

<input type="text" id='comments_values' value="" />

$('.comments').each(function() { 
    $('#comments_values').val($(this).text());
});
```

ну и естественным образом это будет вам вставлять в инпут последнее значение.

Опишите пример `html` пожалуйста.

п.с. [тест](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/fS5Sf/)

**обновился** после вашего коммента, тогда так:

```
$('.comments').each(function() {

    var comment = $(this).text();

    var values = $('#comments_values').val();

    $('#comments_values').val(values + ' ' + comment);

});
```

п.с. [тест](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/fS5Sf/1/)

Comment: @Maris,  Вы все правильно написали. Выглядит именно так.

Comment: главное чтобы вы логику поняли.

Comment: @Maris, огромное спасибо! Все отлично :)